# Coherent detection in fading channel

Tags: digital-communications, fading-channel, coherence

I want to design an optimum receiver for a fading AWGN channel for ML Detection. I know that in the case of non-coherent communication we have to use an energy detector(even when the fading channel is used).
But I am not sure about ML detection in Rayleigh fading when fade amplitude and angle are known to the receiver(i.e. coherent detection).

I have tried using mathematics, but have not made much progress:

$$y=hx + n$$ where $\mathbb E[|h^2|]=1$ and $x = \pm a$ and has Rayleigh distribution. $h$ is the complex channel gain and $|h|$ has Raleigh distribution.

$$h^*y = h^*hx+h^*n$$
$$h^*y = |h|^2x+h^*n$$
$$\frac{h^*}{|h|}y = |h|x + \frac{h^*}{|h|}n$$
Taking the real parts
$$r=|h|x^{'}+z$$

Will $r$ be like the usual AWGN signal? How to draw ML-receiver for it?
Any hint or reference text will be appreciated.

Comment: ML receiver for what kind of transmit signal?

Comment: @MarcusMüller For any general PSK or QAM signal, won't it be the same for all?

Comment: no, it wouldn't. The ML-detector for BPSK in AWGN is the sign of the real part. For 1024-QAM, it can't be that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ok, if I want to calculate for 16PSK and 16QAM then? Thanks.